# how to group radio buttons with different names

Tags: javascript, html

```
//group "a"
1 <input type="radio" name="a" value="1" required>
2 <input type="radio" name="a" value="2">
3 <input type="radio" name="a" value="3">
4 <input type="radio" name="a" value="4">

//group "b"
1 <input type="radio" name="b" value="1" required>
2 <input type="radio" name="b" value="2">
3 <input type="radio" name="b" value="3">
4 <input type="radio" name="b" value="4">
```

how to deselect radio button from group "a" with value "1" if i checked radio button from group "b" with same value "1", but not deselect radio button from group "a" with value "1" if i checked radio button from group "b" with different value "2"

Comment: Are other values also codependent (2 and 2, 3 and 3...) or just the first ones?

Comment: You need javascript for this. Have you attempted anything on your own?

Comment: @El_Vanja yes i want 2 and 2, 3 and 3--- as well and yes i tried this

Comment: $("input[type='radio']").click(function (event) {       
            $("input[type='radio']").prop('checked',false);
            $(this).prop('checked',true);      
    });

Comment: the problem is it removes all checked radio buttons

Comment: Alright, let's say that when clicking b with same value unchecks a. What if a is clicked with the same value again? Should it uncheck b?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems a better approach would be to disable the corresponding values.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
    function disableCorrespondingRadioButton(name, value) {
        // fetch all inputs of given name
        // we need to iterate them all to enable those that might have been disabled earlier
        $('input[name="' + name + '"]').each(function (index, radio) {
            // disable the one of same value as the checked value
            if (radio.value == value) {
                radio.disabled = true;
            } else {
                radio.disabled = false;
            }
        });
    }
    // assign same functionality to both radios' onchange event handler
    $('input[name="a"]').change(function () {
        disableCorrespondingRadioButton('b', $(this).val());
    });
    $('input[name="b"]').change(function () {
        disableCorrespondingRadioButton('a', $(this).val());
    });
});
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    Group "a"
    1 <input type="radio" name="a" value="1" required>
    2 <input type="radio" name="a" value="2">
    3 <input type="radio" name="a" value="3">
    4 <input type="radio" name="a" value="4">
    <br>
    Group "b"
    1 <input type="radio" name="b" value="1" required>
    2 <input type="radio" name="b" value="2">
    3 <input type="radio" name="b" value="3">
    4 <input type="radio" name="b" value="4">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This way whenever a value is selected on one of the radio buttons, the same value in the other one will be disabled. It will send a clearer message to the user than unchecking the option.

Answer (score 1):

I use classes for this, I see you need one choice  from each line and they can not be of same value?

This way you can add as much classes you want and connect them as you want and do all sort of combinations on radio buttons and check-boxes while your form names and values stay the same for form submit-ion.

```js
$('input.a').on('change', function() {
    $('input.a').not(this).prop('checked', false);  
});
$('input.b').on('change', function() {
    $('input.b').not(this).prop('checked', false);  
});
$('input.c').on('change', function() {
    $('input.c').not(this).prop('checked', false);  
});
$('input.d').on('change', function() {
    $('input.d').not(this).prop('checked', false);  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="a" type="radio" name="a" value="1" required>1
<input class="b" type="radio" name="a" value="2">2
<input class="c" type="radio" name="a" value="3">3
<input class="d" type="radio" name="a" value="4">4
</br>

<input class="a" type="radio" name="b" value="1" required>1
<input class="b" type="radio" name="b" value="2">2
<input class="c" type="radio" name="b" value="3">3
<input class="d" type="radio" name="b" value="4">4
```